# Problem with Wireshark on Wifi

Tags: wireshark

I am using wireshark over wifi from my network card Atheros AR9825 network card but it but it is showing the following error. What is the issue?

""The capture session could not be initiated (failed to set hardware filter to promiscuous mode)""

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On most WIFi cards you need special drivers that promiscuous mode can be enabled.

Comment: Yes, although this is presumably on Windows, given the term "hardware filter" in the message, and most Wi-Fi drivers for Windows don't support promiscuous mode.  Drivers for Windows Vista and later might support *monitor* mode, but WinPcap doesn't support that, and, therefore, neither does Wireshark.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you run Wireshark with administrative privileges by holding `CTRL` + `SHIFT` when you run it, or right-clicking it and pressing "Run as Administrator".

Promiscuous mode is used to make the wireless card listen to everything that it can understand, not just information that is addressed to it.

Answer (score 0):

> The capture session could not be initiated (failed to set hardware filter to promiscuous mode)

That sounds as if you're running on Windows.  Microsoft explicitly say that "Native Wi-Fi" 802.11 dissectors should *not* support promiscuous mode.

If this is on Windows, try capturing with promiscuous mode *not* checked.  That will only see Wi-Fi traffic to and from your machine, but that's all you can do with Wireshark on Windows unless you get an [AirPcap adapter](http://www.riverbed.com/products-solutions/products/performance-management/wireshark-enhancement-products/Wireless-Traffic-Packet-Capture.html).